It is possible to define finite path in looped graphs?
I am not so into the graph theory so maybe the question is nonsense. The notion of path and cycles in directed or undirected graph is clear from an untuition perspective. But if we move to looped graphs (ie. a node can have a loop) it is still possible to define a finite path between nodes where some vertex in between are looped? Can someone point me to some literature references?
Thanks in advance
Paolo

Because the answer to this question follows directly from appropriate definitions of graphs and paths, I would suggest introductions to the mathematical concepts of graph theory, such as Oystein Ore's classic (short, and inexpensive) introduction, Graphs and Their Uses.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I refer to the definition by  Bonty and Murty where a graph is defined using incident map.  The definition of loop is and edge that is associated to a single vertex while a path is defined to be "a simple graph whose vertices can be arranged in a linear sequence in such a way that two vertices are adjacent if they are consecutive in the sequence, and are nonadjacent otherwise. "

So according to this definition the following graph where $V={v_1, v_2,v_3 }$, $ E= {1}$ and $ip(1) \mapsto {v_1,v_2}$, $ip(1) \mapsto {v_2,v_3}$ is a path but the following one no  $V={v_1, v_2,v_3 }$, $ E= {1}$ and $ip(1) \mapsto {v_1,v_2}$, $ip(1) \mapsto {v_2,v_3}$ $ip(1) \mapsto {v_1,v_1}$

A graph $G$ a set of vertices $V$ along with a subset $E\subseteq V\times V$ called edges.  It's that simple.  A path is a finite sequence of edges $(v_1,w_1),(v_2,w_2),\ldots,(v_n,w_n)$ where $v_{i+1}=w_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots, n-1.$  A "loop" is any edge of the form $(v,v).$ As an example, let $V={v}$ and $G={(v,v)}.$ The sequence $(v,v),(v,v)$ is a path in $G.$ An example conforming with your question (there's a loop on a distinct intermediate vertex) is $V={1,2,3}$ and $G = {(1,2),(2,3),(2,2)}.$ There are many paths from $1$ to $3,$ such as $(1,2),(2,3)$ and $(1,2),(2,2),(2,3).$

as I state I refer to the notation of graph that use the incident map not the classical one. I get your point but for me you definition of path is not unique because as per your example a path can also be (1,2) (2,2) (2,2) (2,3) and in this case the lenght of a path is not inquely defined

Your post does not ask about unique paths: it asks about "finite" paths.  Perhaps you mis-typed something?  BTW, how a graph is described is a separate matter: it doesn't mean your sense of "graph" is any different from the usual one.  If it does, then please explain what your definition is!
